# Reading header and footer of slide notes of Power point slide using C#

Tags: c#, console-application, powerpoint

Reading header and footer of slide note of Power point slide using  C# and i am using **DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging** ? .
Following code contains **NotesSlidePart** section, where i need to get header and footer of note (not header and footer of slide ) .

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TRackChaePPTX
{
    public class pptx
    {
        private string fullFileName;
        private bool hasreviewcommentexist = false;
        private readonly object StyleTickmark;

       public bool GetCommentsFromPresentation(string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                using (PresentationDocument pptDoc =PresentationDocument.Open(fileName, false))
                {
                    List<string> PPtCommentList = new List<string>();
                    List<string> lstNotes = new List<string>();

                   
                    foreach (SlidePart slide in pptDoc.PresentationPart.SlideParts)
                    {


                        SlideCommentsPart slideCommentsPart = slide.SlideCommentsPart;

                        if (slideCommentsPart != null && slide.SlideCommentsPart.CommentList != null)
                        {
                            if (slide.SlideCommentsPart.CommentList.Count() > 0)
                            {
                                hasreviewcommentexist = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (slide.NotesSlidePart != null)
                        {
                            if (slide.NotesSlidePart.NotesSlide.Count() > 0 && slide.NotesSlidePart.NotesSlide.InnerText != "")
                            {

         // Console.writeLine(Header and footer text of slide note...)
                                if (slide.NotesSlidePart.NotesSlide.InnerText.Length > 1)
                                {
                                    hasreviewcommentexist = true;
                                    break;
                                }


                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            hasreviewcommentexist = false;
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                hasreviewcommentexist = false;
            }
            return hasreviewcommentexist;
        }

    }
}
```

**Used DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging in the above Code.**

Answer (score 0):

By default slide have a note section for each slide ,by the above code i am getting both note for the slide and header and footer of the slide note, I need only note of the slide or skip the header and footer content.
Thank you